# Rearranging expression

Tags: replacement, rule

My goal is to place the terms related to q and r in Expression 1 in one place as much as possible, like Expression 2.(Alpha and beta in the expression are constants, and q and r are variables.) How can I process expression 1 to make it like expression 2? (I can't think of an appropriate function, and I think I might have to use a rule function. I'm posting a question to ask for help.

(Expression 1)

```
  Exp[-q]  q^(-1 + \[Beta])  (1 - r)^(\[Beta] - 1) (q r)^(\[Alpha] - 
    1) q
```

[image]

(Expression 2)

```
q^(-1 + \[Alpha] + \[Beta]) Exp[-q]   r^(\[Alpha] - 1)  (1 - 
    r)^(\[Beta] - 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Use `PowerExpand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr = 
  Exp[-q] q^(-1 + \[Beta]) (1 - r)^(\[Beta] - 1) (q r)^(\[Alpha] - 1) q
```

A *"completely correct result"* according to the documentation for `PowerExpand`

```
PowerExpand[expr, Assumptions -> True]
```

[image]

The wanted result in explicit form

```
PowerExpand[expr, Assumptions -> q > 0 || r > 0]
```

[image]

From the documentation for `PowerExpand`

*"The default setting for the `Assumption` option is
`Automatic`, corresponding to a maximal set of assumptions."*

Therefore, also giving the wanted result:

```
PowerExpand[expr, Assumptions -> Automatic]
```

or, like Syed's comment,

```
PowerExpand[expr]
```

Comment: Thank  you for your answer.  Could I ask one more question about usage of PowerExpand? PowerExpand[(x y z)^3,{x}] is expected to be x^3 (y x)^3 according  to doc., but is there a reason why it becomes x^3 y^3 z^3?

Comment: ` x^3 (y x)^3` would be  `x^6 y^3`, i.e numerically different. For this reason alone it cannot accord to the doc. `PowerExpand[(x y z)^3,{x}]` doesn't do anything unless you assign a value to `x`. For example, `PowerExpand[(x y z)^3, Assumptions -> x == 1]` gives `y^3 z^3`

Comment: There was a typo in my question.x^3 (y x)^3 ---> x^3 (y z)^3. I apologize. Strangely, when I do PowerExpand[(x y z)^3, {x}], x (y z)^3, unexpectedly  x^3 y^3 z^3 shows. However If I do PowerExpand[(x y z)^k, {x}], I got desired x^k (y z)^k, which is peculiar for me.